# Download issue of document library in liferay 6.2 for Chrome while using windows 8 and office 2013

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, liferay, ms-office, document-library

While downloading from document library in liferay 6.2 ,I am getting some issues in chrome like  all the files are saved without extension at the time of downloading. This issues happens for the combination of windows 8 + office 2013 and windows 7+office 2010

```
                              long fileEntryId = getResume.getFileEntryId();
                              FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(fileEntryId);
                              fileEntry = fileEntry.toEscapedModel();
                              long folderId = fileEntry.getFolderId();
                              String title = fileEntry.getTitle();
                              mimeType = fileEntry.getMimeType();
                              System.out.println("LULU JEET: "+fileEntry.getMimeType());

                              if (resourceRequest != null) {
                                     themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) resourceRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
                              }

                              String fileUrl = themeDisplay.getPortalURL()
                                            + themeDisplay.getPathContext() + "/documents/"
                                            + themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() + "//" + folderId
                                            + "//"
                                            + HttpUtil.encodeURL(HtmlUtil.unescape(title));
                              jobArray.put(fileUrl);
                       }

                       jsonFeed.put("jobArray", jobArray);
                       resourceResponse.setContentType(mimeType);
                       resourceResponse.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=Resume-" + candidateName + ".docx");
                       resourceResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                       resourceResponse.getWriter().write(jsonFeed.toString());
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

So in this code i am using FileEntry for this operation.But for chrome it is not working.Somebody please help.

Comment: Try to add following --> resourceResponse.addProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFileName + "\"");

Comment: no this is not working

Comment: Along with file name you need to fetch file extension and add both in content disposition

Comment: can you please help with some code ??

Comment: resourceResponse.addProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFileName.<append-extension> + "\"");